# Android Studio can't import a java from 'generated_java' folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apollo-android

I implement a package 'apollo-android' and generate 'FeedQuery' java file from the 'schema.json'. But I can't import that 'FeedQuery' java file to my project.

Comment: is FeedQuery public class?

Comment: yes, the FeedQuery is public class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apollo android plugin really depends on the android gradle plugin. So if your generated classes are in a `java-library` module, you will not be able to import them.

Assuming you placed your graphql queries in an android module, please make sure that you have created a directory structure same as your module source directory structure under `/graphql`

For example if your module directory structure is as follows

`src/main/java/com/example/`

Then create the graphql directory structure as follows.

`src/main/graphql/com/example/`

After doing this, clean and rebuild and try importing classes again.